# Laravel php, scandir carry onif file doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I have an Ical folder which contain with file name from 1-96.ical. However some of these files are empty (size 0kb) and throw me an error saying:

```
[Exception]
  The file path or URL 'public/ical/96.ics' does not exist.
```

However what I want to do is if it doesn't exist (while it does but is empty) carry on with rest of the files.

```
 public function handle()
    {
        $files = scandir('public/ical/', 1);
        $type = "Standard Event";
        foreach ($files as $file) {
        $ical = new ICal('public/ical/'.$file);
        $events = ($ical->events());
        $list = [];
        foreach($events as $event){
            if(!empty($event->rrule)){
                $lines = explode("\n", $event->rrule);
            foreach($lines as $line) {
                $parts = explode(';', $line);
                $frequency = $until = $day = $interval = null;
                    foreach($parts as $part) {
                    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part);
                        switch($key) {
                            case 'FREQ':
                            $frequency = $value;
                            break;
                            case 'INTERVAL':
                            $interval = $value;
                            break;
                            case 'BYDAY' :
                            $day = $value;
                            break;
                            case 'UNTIL' :
                            $until = $value;
                            break;
                            case 'BYMONTH' :
                            $month = $value;
                            break;
                            case 'BYMONTHDAY' :
                            $monthday = $value;
                        }
                    if(empty($until)) {
                        $until = "NULL";
                    }
                }
            $data = [
                'startdate' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($event->dtstart)),
                'endate' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($event->dtend)), 
                'startime' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($event->dtstart_tz)), 
                'endtime' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($event->dtend_tz)), 
                'title' => $event->summary,
                'type' => $type,
                'frequency' => $frequency,
                'interval' => $interval,
                'weekday' => $day,
                'monthday' => $monthday,
                'month' => $month,
                'until' => date("T-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($until)),
                'description' => $event->description
            ];
            array_push($list, $data);
        }
    }
}
    $this->info("Event Retrieved");
    Event::insert($list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of library for this? What does the `ICal` class do?

Comment: it is just a library that reads the ical file

Answer (score -1):

Use Laravel's `File` library to check in your loop:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if(!File::exists('public/ical/'.$file)) continue; // skips to the next iteration of the loop
    $ical = new ICal('public/ical/'.$file);
```

if `File::exists()` doesn't work, try `Storage::exists()`. I believe they changed the naming somewhere along the line.

Comment: I tried both, file doesn't work and storage gives me permission denied